# Change the way zune syncs music files from computer

Tags: lumia, sync, zune, 7.5

I am using Zune 4.8.2345.0, whenever I connect my mobile to my computer, it syncs music files, and stores it in the music folder. I am annoyed by the way it syncs it. It saves in folders by Artist name instead I want to save it by the Album name. Does anyone know how I can change it?

Comment: Are you referring to files moving from your phone to your computer or the other way?

Comment: @karancan i am referring files moving from my phone to computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zune controls the directory structure of synced music and you can't change it because the music is indexed along with the transfer, which is why you can readily access your music without another round of indexing on your phone. That process is evident on phones and apps (namely android) that allow a flexible directory structure at a cost of the device having to re-index the directory whenever files are added/changed/removed.